# API : Return viewmodel/response based on Enum value

Tags: c#, enums, return-type

I'm working on an API endpoint working with enums, and I need to return a different Response (a class with different properties) based on enum value. I'm sure Generics can help me here but I can't figure how nor where.

Multiple entry points calling a common method (I have 16 differents types) that call a logic function :

```
public class ApiController : BaseController
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetType1(FilterEnum filter)
    {
        return await this.PrepareResponseForFilterAndType(filter, TypeEnum.Type1);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> GetType2(FilterEnum filter)
    {
        return await this.PrepareResponseForFilterAndType(filter, TypeEnum.Type2);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> GetType16(FilterEnum filter)
    {
        return await this.PrepareResponseForFilterAndType(filter, TypeEnum.Type16);
    }

    private async Task<IActionResult> PrepareResponseForFilterAndType(FilterEnum filter, TypeEnum type)
    {
        // Call to logic, with return type of IEnumerable<IResponse>
        var response = await Logic.DoBusiness(this.UnitOfWork, filter, type);

        //// Do stuff before return

        return this.Json(response);
    }
}
```

In logic, I apply filters (both FilterEnum and TypeEnum) to grab requested data, update data if necessary, whatever.

Then, I have to return a different Response depending on the TypeEnum: most responses share common values, but not all, and lots of responses have specific values.

My issue is here: the code work, it's not perfect, but it work. Still, it smell.

I want to change what the Interface and the Switch allow me to do for something better and cleaner.

As you will see with the interface and classes that implements it, all properties from the interface must be in each Type1Response, Type2Response, ..., Type16Response classes as well. That means if some of the interface properties are not present for this "TypeX", they will still be in the response with a null value that is not meaningful for this Type.

```
public class Logic
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<IResponse>> DoBusiness(UnitOfWork unitOfWork, FilterEnum filter, TypeEnum type)
    {
        //// Apply filter and return a collection of the relevant type from the db
        var filteredElements = unitOfWork.ElementRepository.ListForFilterAndType(filter, type);

        IEnumerable<IResponse> response = null;

        switch (type)
        {
            case TypeEnum.Type1:
                response = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Type1Response>>(filteredElements);
                break;
            case TypeEnum.Type2:
                response = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Type2Response>>(filteredElements);
                break;
            case TypeEnum.Type16:
                response = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Type16Response>>(filteredElements);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Interface and TypeXResponses

```
public interface IResponse
{
    int Id { get; set; } // Mostly in all types but not everywhere

    string Name { get; set; }

    string Type { get; set; }

    string Images { get; set; } // Needed for some types to format multiple urls
}

public class Type1Response : IResponse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Images { get; set; } // No images for this type but will be present in the response cause of interface

    public int Free { get; set; }

    public int Capacity { get; set; }
}

public class Type2Response : IResponse
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // No id nor name for this type but I must have them here cause of the interface

    public string Name { get; set; } // No id nor name for this type but I must have them here cause of the interface

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Images { get; set; }
}

public class Type16Response : IResponse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Images { get; set; }
}
```

So I'm looking for a cleaner way to implement this, that work better (no unnecessary null values), without duplicating 16 times the same code, except the TypeXResponse.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to show a bit more code than what you've provided, as I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: this question may be better suited for CodeReview sister site on the exchange network.  It seems like you're basically asking for a cleaner way to do this functional code, right?

Comment: I added some code. @IanKemp

Comment: It's clearly to do the same code cleaner, but never went to the CodeReview site. @BrettCaswell

Comment: I posted the question on CodeReview.

Comment: What's with all the [Square Brackets] around [Enum] and [ElementEnum]? Is there some new C# syntax that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Nope, it is just GetType1, GetType2, as Get[ElementEnum], it is something repeated numerous times. I have clarified the code.

Comment: You are on the right way, just add the enum value or name to the route like [HttpGet("{0}")] or [HttpGet("{Type1}")] probably you have to write own route constraint too but is not a big deal - then you should be able to access the endpoints like /.../.../0?id=123 or /.../.../Type1?id=123 - and so you have differend endpoint foreach enum value

Comment: I'm fine with the entry, it's the return type (Type1Response, Type2Response, ... Type 20Response) my issue here.

Comment: So you're using an interface, but don't want all classes to implement the properties in the interface??? Then just don't put them in the interface.

Comment: I know what means using an interface, but as explained, it is not the best way in this case. I want a cleaner way to achieve the same result, and if possible, without the interface as it cause null values returned that are not meiningful. I have try with inheritance, some generic implementations too but I couldn't make work anything except this one here. I think what I'm looking for is "pretty common" and someone might be able to help me to solve this case.